# how to download multiple images using restful webservice

Tags: rest, java-8, jersey-2.0

Please let me know How can I download multiple images using Restful webservice? I have a requirement to export multiple images from restful webservice.

I am able to send a single file using below code.

```
  final String FILE_PATH = "D:\\DSC_0493.jpg";

  File file = new File(FILE_PATH);

  Response.ResponseBuilder response1 = Response.ok((Object) file);
  response1.header("Content-Disposition",
          "attachment; filename=image_from_server.png");
```

Comment: Would a zip file not work for this?

Comment: Would RESTFul not return JSON objects? Where is the rest of the code that stream the image?

Comment: @Hank D, It may work, But here the client is a android app, Not sure Is it feasible at client side or not.